# Sequence of perfect matchings

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G=W\times H$ be an infinite countable bipartite graph satysfing the conditions of Hall’s Marriage Theorem and such that each vertex has finite degree. Let $G_i$ be the subgraph of $G$ that contains the first $i$ vertices of $W$ and all their neighbours in $H$. Does the sequence of perfect matchings of the $G_i$'s stabilize? i.e., Does the match of any $w_i$ remain constant for the perfect matchings of the $G_n$ for $n>N$ big enough?

My goal is to show that $G$ contains a perfect matching from $W$ to $H$.

Comment: How do you define your sequence of matchings? Do you want to prove this for any given sequence of matchings? If so, this is false, you can easily build a sequence that alternate between two different infinite matchings.

Comment: @caduk I had no particular sequence of matchings. It is good to know that is not true in general. I will think about some special sequences that satisfy this convergence property.